# Bind Ruby TCP Client to a specific IP address

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a server with 4 ip addresses and four clients that each register their ip address with a service. Each client runs the same ruby script that connects via a TCP socket to the service.

The problem I have is all four scripts are connecting via the same IP address so three are receiving authorisation errors because they have the wrong ip address.

Is it possible to tell the TCP client to use a specific ip address?